# Hibernate mapping of collection of a column value from the same table

Tags: java, hibernate

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.TABLE_A (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    value character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    linked_id integer
)
```

I want to know the hibernate annotations to complete my entity class:

```
public class TableA {
    @Id @Column(name="id", unique=true)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="value", nullable=false)
    private String value;
    // missing annotations
    private String linkedValue;
}
```

So that I get the `linkedValue` (which comes from a self join to `TABLE_A` on `linked_id = id` and select from the column `value`) as String in my entity class `TableA`.

Similarly, in case it is not one-to-one:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.TABLE_A (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    value character varying(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.TABLE_B (
    table_a_id integer NOT NULL,
    linked_table_a_id integer NOT NULL
)
```

What are the hibernate annotations to complete my entity class:

```
public class TableA {
    @Id @Column(name="id", unique=true)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="value", nullable=false)
    private String value;
    // missing annotations
    private Set<String> linkedValues;
}
```

So that I get the set of `linkedValues` (which comes from joining `TABLE_A` to `TABLE_B` on `id = table_a_id` and joining `TABLE_A` again on `linked_table_a_id = id` to select from the column `value`) in my entity class `TableA`.

Prefer answers without needing to introduce and extra entity class `TableB`. Thank you.

Comment: `linked_value integer` - why `private String linkedValue;` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat because I only need the String value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  JPA 2.0 's `@ElementCollection`:

```
public class TableA {

   @Id @Column(name="id", unique=true)
   private int id;

   @Column(name="value", nullable=false)
   private String value;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "TABLE_A",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "linked_id"))
    @Column(name = "value")
    private Set<String> linkedValues = new HashSet<String>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please also give the answer to the second part of the question?

Comment: Which question ? Also , if you think my answer is helpful or already solve the problem of this question (i.e. `mapping of collection of a column value from the same table`) , please first upvote it first.

Comment: Wait, which part of my question were you answering? The first part of the question is not a Set. The second part of the question involves a second table `TABLE_B`, how did your answer work for either?

Comment: Well , I am answering based on your title "mapping the **collection of a column** value from the **same** table". Actually , your question is a little bit confused which the content does not match with the title , would you please modify and clarify it ?

Comment: The value that I want is from the same table, which is why I have that title. I don't know which part is not clear to you?

Comment: Then it involves another table `TABLE_B` or not ?Sometime you say it involve Table_B , sometimes you say it is from the same table ......  Actually do you really try or understand my answer ? It already can map the collection of value from the same table...

Comment: Yes may be I failed to understand your answer. How can you not use `TABLE_B` in your answer to map a Set/Collection of `linkedValues` to the entity `TableA`? The one-to-many relationship is stored in `TABLE_B` in the database.

Comment: Because your title says ""mapping the **COLLECTION** of a column value from the **SAME** table". So that why it is very confused ......

Comment: I think you missed what I said in the question: "the set of linkedValues (which comes from joining TABLE_A to TABLE_B on id = table_a_id and joining TABLE_A again on linked_table_a_id = id to select from the column value)". This is very basic one-to-many association. The final values required are in `TABLE_A` the value column, but in order to get the correct values, you first need to do a join to `TABLE_B`, then join back to `TABLE_A` to get the value. If you still cannot understand I have nothing more to add.

Comment: Well, my answer exactly is answering this requirement.  Don't know why it is so complex to introduce TABLE_B , actually you can self join TABLE_A itself to have this one-to-many relationship... Please verify it by actually try it......

Comment: I fail to see how you can have a one-to-many relationship WITHIN `TABLE_A` without requiring `TABLE_B`. If what you have in mind is true, what does your `TABLE_A` look like? e.g. (1, a, 2), (1, b, 3), (1, c, 4), (2, d, null), (3, e, null), (4, f, null)? First question to ask yourself, how can you have multiple linked values? By repeating entries of 1s? Second question to ask yourself, if id is not unique, then how can id be the primary key @id? Try it yourself and you would see your answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: TableA exactly has the same schema of what mentioned in your question . So given (1,a,null) , (2,b,1) , (3,c,1) , (4,d,1) , that means ID1 is linked to ID2 , ID3 and ID4 .Think one more time and does it make sense now ?

Comment: Sure, now use your example, add entries so that ID2 is linked to ID3 and ID4. See how you cannot avoid repeating the same id? Not saying your answer did not work in your own setting, but your answer is not applicable to my question.

Comment: Hey , then it is not `one-to-many` , it is `many-to-many` . In `one-to-many` case , once ID3 is linked to ID1 , it cannot linked to other ID..... Your question says it is `one-to-many` ......... Now you say you want `many-to-many`.....  So that 's why the question is very confusing indeed......

Comment: I did not ever limit the reverse mapping to non-mapped ids, thats why I said you are answering your own setting instead of my question. `TABLE_A` to `TABLE_B` is one-to-many. `TABLE_B` to `TABLE_A` is many-to-one.

Comment: No I am answering based on your  requirement mentioned in the question , which is one-to-many  .In this case , what I suggest is already can achieve this. You don't need to have tableB in this case which is a ugly ,stupid and complex implementation . This is what I suggested but it is your choice to go on the ugly one.

Comment: You can create your own question and answer your own, be my guest. But you are not answering my question here. Can you or can you not answer my question that involves both `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B`? If not, I am going to neg your answer (at the same time feel free to neg my question, you are welcome).

Comment: No , I am answering your question with a very solid solutions and counter suggestions (i.e don't need tableB) which totally satisfy your intention mentioned in the question (i.e. `one-to-many` ,  map the collection from the `same` table). Also , not only I am writing the solutions to you , I am also writing to the someone who may face the same problem in the future . So be the community guest and be open minded with different solutions and implementation to achieve the same thing. Well , feel free to downvote my answer . But if you do , I think it is a very non-sense decision......

Comment: You answered your own setting, not mine. You asked for clarification and I have clarified already: `TABLE_B` is required for the many-to-many self referencing relationship within `TABLE_A`, hence in the database it is represented by two one-to-many relationships between `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B`. Your answer did not fit my question. Also you missed the first part of the question about one-to-one. If you are not updating your answer, you are leaving me no choice.

Comment: That 's why I say your questions is very very confusing. And based on what we talked throughout the comment , you keep on clarify that it is `one-to-many` at first but finally change your mind to `many-to-many`. Okay , never mind ,but would you please update your question and its title such that it is not so confusing , I still see the wording `one-to-many` ,  `map from the same table`.....Or do you expect people will go through all comments in this thread to try to understand your requirement .... I think probably not....If you are not updating your question ,you are leaving me no choice too.

Comment: I don't think you have the same understanding of relational database relationship as me. Anyhow, l don't think you need more clarification. Your choice is always there: to show you know the answer or not. And really, nothing is stopping you from providing a more than enough answer, by giving examples for 1-1, 1-n, n-n. No idea why you could ever only just pick one to answer, unless you just know that one.